# Is in-canera noise reduction useful for video?

Tags: noise-reduction, noise

I've read different opinions online, but they always seem to talk about stills. So, is NR useful for shooting videos? Or does it mess up with the image too much?

I'm shooting on a Panasonic Lumix G7, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

My general rule is to do as little in the camera as possible (exposure, shutter). Leave everything else for post. It's not expected that the camera will have the best available NR or compression etc, and if you do it while recording you can't undo it later.

Of course if you'll never do any post, do what gives you the best result.

Comment: There can be an advantage to doing some things in camera, such as white balance and possibly noise correction if it is done before the in-camera  compression

Comment: Agreed on WB, as long as it isn't continuous auto white balance. I'm not doctrinaire on the subject, I just like to preserve as many options as reasonably possible.